# Ruby On Rails: Understanding Form Submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have been previously working on Spring MVC mostly so thought about understanding ROR for a change.

I was going though the tutorials on CodeAcademy, wherein I got a little confused by the following Form Submission mechanism.

So here's a sample form.

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>  
  <div class="field"> 
    <%= f.label :message %><br> 
    <%= f.text_area :content %> 
  </div> 
  <div class="actions"> 
    <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

The corresponding action handler in Controller is as follows:

```
def create
 @message = Message.new(message_params)
 if @message.save
   redirect_to '/messages'
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end

private 
def message_params 
  params.require(:message).permit(:content) 
end
```

I am confused by the following line `params.require(:message).permit(:content)`
Since `:message` is a label field, it should always have a value. So `.required(:message)` should always be `true` and the method `message_params` should always return the value of the textbox. Correct?

I am not sure if I understand it completely. Could someone explain it a bit clearly.

Comment: It's to do with strong parameters: http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is just the label of the `content` field.

The `require(:message)` is the parameter hash of your form and `permit(:content)` is your permitted `content` parameter. So your parameter hash could look something like this:

```
{
  message: {
    content: "Your content here..."
  }
}
```

This technique is called "[Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)".

Comment: Just to clarify, suppose I need to pass in 1 more input field say Name, will I have to use another parameter hash for that? just like message??

Comment: If you add for example `name` to the hash, than the only thing you have to do, is to add this in your `permit` call. You will find more information about it in the docs. But if you just want to send a `name` parameter directly, you can access it directly by calling `params[:name]`. Btw you can also get nested parameters directly by calling `params[:message][:content]` for example.